# Sum Column Data in a Database using VC++ Win Forms

Tags: c#, c++, sql, visual-c++

I would like to sum the following two columns from my database table and display it in form of a chart. My code below will run correct, but show empty chart result. Please help !

```
c.Open();
            DateTime startDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(textBox1.Text);
            DateTime endDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(textBox2.Text);
            string query = "SELECT * FROM People_Tracking WHERE Enter_Exit_Time BETWEEN @startDateTime AND @endDateTime ;";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, c);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@startDateTime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = startDateTime;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@endDateTime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = endDateTime;
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable t = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(t);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = t;


string query1 = "SELECT Sum(Number_of_Enterance) FROM People_Tracking ;";       
string query2 = "SELECT Sum(Number_of_Exits) FROM People_Tracking ;";

this.chart1.Series["DateTime"].Points.AddXY("Number_of_Enterance", query1);
this.chart1.Series["DateTime"].Points.AddXY("Number_of_Exits", query2);
```

Comment: how did you execute to get result from DB?

Comment: Summing two columns of a DataTable only gives you one point.  Don't you want to plot every point?

Comment: @jdweng. I wan it like having sum1 as 20 and sum2 as 30, then I plot the 20 and 30 in form of a pie chart.

Comment: Thank you everyone ! I got it using the following:


                int sum1 = 0;
                int sum2 = 0;
                for (int i=0; i< dataGridView1.Rows.Count;++i)
                {
                    sum1 += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                    sum2 += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
                }
            this.chart1.Series["DateTime"].Points.AddXY("Number_of_Enterance", sum1.ToString());             this.chart1.Series["DateTime"].Points.AddXY("Number_of_Exits", sum2.ToString());